# QT creator 4.9.2 with ROS plugin

Tags: qt, ros

I am using QT creator 4.9.2 with Ros plugin

I have the following problem. I can compile a catkin project inside QT creator fine but for some reason I get loads of Lexical or preprocessor errors on all my header file includes (also ones like iostream). I also have no intellisense. Again it all compiles fine but I can't click on include files or have any intellisense for this particular project

The weird thing is that another catkin project builds fine with the same QT Creator version but doesn't have any of these problems and i have set it up in  what I believe is the exact same way but obviously they are different CmakeList.txt files for each project.

I've tried cleaning the project and rebuilding but no joy. Any ideas on what I could try to resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Seems you have two version of Qt on your system and qtcreator build kit is selecting the wrong one. How do you install your Qt and Qtcreator and which version?

Comment: You are correct. 
I first  installed Qt Creator 4.13.1 Based on Qt 5.15.1 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit). 
I then installed Qt Creator 4.9.2 Based on Qt 5.12.4 (GCC 7.4.0, 64 bit) which included the ROS plug in

Comment: Not sure what I should do next. Is it possible to have both on my system at the same time? Is there a way to tell it to use one over the other and stop these errors?. My understanding is that 4.9.2 is the latest when it comes to using ROS packages.

Comment: Yes you can have many version at the same time but you should be sure about selecting correct qt build kit for your project. By the way, if you installed both version with qtcreator use the related one. You can find it in INSTALLED_DIR/Tools/QtCreator/bin/

Comment: OK - so I would agree I must have configured the kit incorrectly. It didn't auto detect so I just used the temporary one but this must be incorrect. How do you see what kit it is pointing too? Sorry for the stupid question. I'm ok with C++ but pretty new to QT environment

Comment: Follow this link to add a kit to your qtcreator https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Comment: Many thanks  - I'll give this a go